# How to retrieve all kinds of dates and temporal values from text

Tags: java, date, nlp, gate, temporal

I wanted to retrieve dates and other temporal entities from a set of Strings. Can this be done without parsing the string for dates in JAVA as most parsers deal with a limited scope of input patterns. But input is a manual entry which here and hence ambiguous.

Inputs can be like:

> 12th Sep |mid-March |12.September.2013
>
> Sep 12th |12th September| 2013
>
> Sept 13 |12th, September |12th,Feb,2013

I've gone through many answers on finding date in Java but most of them don't deal with such a huge scope of input patterns.

I've tried using `SimpleDateFormat` class and using some parse() functions to check if parse function breaks which mean its not a date. I've tried using `regex` but I'm not sure if it falls fit in this scenario. I've also used [ClearNLP](https://github.com/clir/clearnlp/tree/master/src) to annotate the dates but it doesn't give a reliable annotation set.

The closest approach to getting these values could be using a `Chain of responsibility` as mentioned below. Is there a library that has a set of patterns for date. I can use that maybe?

Comment: somewhere you have to limit the scope, try to wrap input into your own fixed format.

Comment: @ankur-singhal too late for that buddy I can't change this old data now, its already there, I'm only extracting

Comment: Can you provide some information on what dates should the lines equate to?  `mid-March` is a bit too ambiguous even for human processing.

Comment: mid-March is not a date

Comment: @Identity1 straight forward there is nothing to extract data, it seems more like a data analytic problem, you might need to analyse the complete data, and then come up with some solution. having some keywords like `Sep`, `September`, `th`, `nd`, `rd` etc.

Comment: True I'll correct that @peter.petrov. I needed all temporal entities not neccessarily dates. Yes ankur-singhal you are correct on that. Months, one to four digit numbers and prepositions like "in,on,by,of" are the only tangibles I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! I've finally extracted all sorts of dates/temporal values that can be as generic as :

> mid-March | Last Month | 9/11

To as specific as:

> 11/11/11 11:11:11

This finally happened because of awesome libraries from [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/) and [JAPE](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch8.html#chap:jape)

I've created a more lenient annotation rule in JAPE say 'DateEnhanced' to include certain kinds of dates like "9/11 or 11TH, February- 2001" and used a [Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)  of Java regex on R.H.S. of the 'DateEnhanced' annotations `JAPE RULE`, to filter some unwanted outputs.

Answer (score 2):

A clean and modular approach to this problem would be to use a chain,
every element of the chain tries to match the input string against a regex,
if the regex matches the input string than you can convert the input string to something that can feed a SimpleDateFormat to convert it to the data structure you prefer (Date? or a different temporal representation that better suits your needs) and return it, if the regexp doesn't matches the chain element just delegates to the next element in the chain.

The responsibility of every element of the chain is just to test the regex against the string, give a result or ask the next element of the chain to give it a try.

The chain can be created and composed easily without having to change the implementation of every element of the chain.

In the end the result is the same as in @KirkoR response, with a 'bit' (:D) more code but a modular approach. (I prefer the regex approach to the try/catch one)

Some reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Comment: This is a very relevant thing. This approach can be very helpful. +1 Thanks

Comment: Finally made it. GATE is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You could just implement support for *all the pattern possibilities you can think of*, then document that ... OK, these are all patterns my module supports. You could then throw some `RuntimeException` for all the other possibilities.

Then ... in an iterative way you can keep running your module over the input data, and keep adding support for more date formats until it stops raising any `RuntimeException`.

I think that's the best you can do here if you want to keep it reasonably simple.

Comment: Is there a library that stores such temporal patterns? Some kind of Gazetteer other than `ClearNLP`?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to you very nice implementation of your problem, unfortunetlly in polish: http://koziolekweb.pl/2015/04/15/throw-to-taki-inny-return/

You can use google translator:

https://translate.google.pl/translate?sl=pl&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fkoziolekweb.pl%2F2015%2F04%2F15%2Fthrow-to-taki-inny-return&edit-text=

The code there looks really nice:

```
private static Date convertStringToDate(String s) {                           
    if (s == null || s.trim().isEmpty()) return null;                         
    ArrayList<String> patterns = Lists.newArrayList(YYYY_MM_DD_T_HH_MM_SS_SSS,
            YYYY_MM_DD_T_HH_MM_SS                                             
            , YYYY_MM_DD_T_HH_MM                                              
            , YYYY_MM_DD);                                                    
    for (String pattern : patterns) {                                         
        try {                                                                 
            return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(s);                    
        } catch (ParseException e) {                                          
        }                                                                     
    }                                                                         
    return new Date(Long.valueOf(s));                                         
}
```

Comment: Seems OP does not need just dates, but all "temporal entities" which is a concept that needs a stricter definition IMHO.

Comment: Can `DateFormat` match `12th, September`. Maybe I can write a complicated method using peter's suggestion with a divide and conquer approach

Answer (score 0):

```
    mark.util.DateParser dp = new DateParser();
    ParsePositionEx parsePosition = new ParsePositionEx(0);
    Date startDate = dp.parse("12.September.2013", parsePosition);
    System.out.println(startDate);
```

> output: Thu Sep 12 17:18:18 IST 2013

mark.util.Dateparser is a part of library which is used by [DateNormalizer PR](https://gate.ac.uk/gate/plugins/Tagger_DateNormalizer/src/gate/creole/dates/DateAnnotationNormalizer.java). So in Jape file, we have to just import it.

Comment: This can be used to normalize dates. You can avoid this if you only want to extract dates

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked your question saying "without parsing".