# Facing a problem with using Natty library for converting string to date

Tags: java, list, date, natty

I am trying to find dates in a text that I want to modify. I found that Natty library is helping with this which I didn't know anything about it. Especially click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33547390/1814641) to see what I based on. 
The problem is when I am copying the code from this mentioned link, for the below line NetBeans is showing me the below error:

```
List<Date> dates =new Parser().parse("Start date 11/30/2013 , end date Friday, Sept. 7, 2013").get(0).getDates();
```

` **Error:** *Type List doesn't take parameters*

I tried to take a look of this new library, I found out that `parse()` returns `List<DataGroup>`. I tried this also in my code, but the same error still exist.

I am importing the below for List:

```
import java.awt.List;  
import com.joestelmach.natty.*;  
import java.util.List.*;
```

Where am I doing mistake?

Comment: Are you importing the wrong `List` type? Please show us your import statement/s.

Comment: I did.... thank you

Comment: You want to import `java.util.List` (I think; check the return type of `getDates()` to be sure). So delete `import java.awt.List; ` and delete the asterisk from the last line so it reads `import java.util.List;`.